# DocuSign Connect: Possibility to track when the user change credentials

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

For our integration, we created an integration keys pair and used OAuth 2 flow to obtain access_token.

Then that tokens we use to send documents to DocuSign API.
But we are faced with the next problem - if the user changes the password to his account, our service can not use or refresh the existing token(using the refresh token).  So user should reauthenticate again and then we obtain a new token.

The question is - does DocuSign have webhooks that notify about user profile/credentials changes? Or probably some other suggestions on how we can track that stored access_token is not valid due to credentials changes?

Answer (score 0):

Credentials change does not invalidate OAuth 2.0 tokens. These tokens are valid for 8 hours only and cannot be invalidated (you asked [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977410/docusign-oauth-revoke-access-token/69981162#69981162) that seems to suggest similar confusion).

There's no way using DocuSign connect to track if a user changes their password, but you could potentially do this using [DocuSign Monitor](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/).