# DocuSign oauth: revoke access token

Tags: docusignapi

Token revoke endpoint not working

***Request:***

[Authorization] Bearer {token}

[POST]https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/oauth2/revoke

***Response***:
[Bad Request: 400]

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"The presented token is invalid."}
```

How manually using DocuSign API I can revoke the access token?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you found this endpoint, but you're mixing different things.

While the endpoint does have /oauth2/ in the URL this is not OAuth 2.0

Very sorry about confusion, this endpoint is for the old authentication prior to OAuth 2.0 where tokens never expired and so you can revoke them using this endpoint.

Tokens for OAuth 2.0 expire after 8 hours so there's no need to revoke